# NeedlemanWunsch algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to understand the Hirschberg algorithm and I came across this piece of algorithm from Wikipedia. I do not understand how the NeedlemanWunsch() function works.

```
function Hirschberg(X,Y)
Z = ""
W = ""
if length(X) == 0 or length(Y) == 0
  if length(X) == 0
    for i=1 to length(Y)
      Z = Z + '-'
      W = W + Yi
    end
  else if length(Y) == 0
    for i=1 to length(X)
      Z = Z + Xi
      W = W + '-'
    end
  end
else if length(X) == 1 or length(Y) == 1
  (Z,W) = NeedlemanWunsch(X,Y)
else
  xlen = length(X)
  xmid = length(X)/2
  ylen = length(Y)

  ScoreL = NWScore(X1:xmid, Y)
  ScoreR = NWScore(rev(Xxmid+1:xlen), rev(Y))
  ymid = PartitionY(ScoreL, ScoreR)

  (Z,W) = Hirschberg(X1:xmid, y1:ymid) + Hirschberg(Xxmid+1:xlen, Yymid+1:ylen)
end
return (Z,W)
```

Can someone explain about the NeedlemanWunsch algorithm and how can it be implemented through Python? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a homework/coursework question so I won't give you the full solution. However, I will guide you into producing a working solution.

**Needleman-Wunsch Algorithm**

The Needleman-Wunsch algorithm is a method used to align sequences. It is essentially made up of two components:

1. A similarity matrix, F.
2. A linear penalty gap, d.

When aligning sequences, there can be many possibilities. What this matrix allows you to do is to find the most optimal one and discard all the other sequences.

What you will have to do is:

1. Create a 2-dimensional array to hold the matrix, F.
2. A method to initialise matrix F with the scores.
3. A method to compute the optimal sequence.

**Creating a 2-dimensional array to hold the matrix, F**

You can either use numpy for this, or you could just generate the matrix as follows. Assume you have two sequences A and B:

```
F = [[0 for x in xrange(len(A)] for x in xrange(len(B))]
```

**A method to initialise matrix F with the scores.**

Create a method which takes a parameters the length of each sequence, the linear penalty gap, and the matrix F:

```
def createSimilarityMatrix(lengthOfA, lengthOfB, penalityGap, F):
```

You then need to implement the following pseudo-code:

```
for i=0 to length(A)
  F(i,0) ← d*i
for j=0 to length(B)
  F(0,j) ← d*j
for i=1 to length(A)
  for j=1 to length(B)
  {
    Match ← F(i-1,j-1) + S(Ai, Bj)
    Delete ← F(i-1, j) + d
    Insert ← F(i, j-1) + d
    F(i,j) ← max(Match, Insert, Delete)
  }
```

*Hint*: Research optimal ways to write this algorithm in idiomatic Python. Also note that in the double for-loop at the bottom, you can collapse in a one-liner.

**A method to compute the optimal sequence**

Once you have the similarity matrix done, then you can implement the main algorithm to compute the optimal sequence. For this, create a method which takes your two sequences A and B as parameters:

```
def needlemanWunsch (a, b):
```

You will then need to implement this method using the following pseudocode:

```
AlignmentA ← ""
AlignmentB ← ""
i ← length(A)
j ← length(B)
while (i > 0 or j > 0)
{
  if (i > 0 and j > 0 and F(i,j) == F(i-1,j-1) + S(Ai, Bj))
  {
    AlignmentA ← Ai + AlignmentA
    AlignmentB ← Bj + AlignmentB
    i ← i - 1
    j ← j - 1
  }
  else if (i > 0 and F(i,j) == F(i-1,j) + d)
  {
    AlignmentA ← Ai + AlignmentA
    AlignmentB ← "-" + AlignmentB
    i ← i - 1
  }
  else (j > 0 and F(i,j) == F(i,j-1) + d)
  {
    AlignmentA ← "-" + AlignmentA
    AlignmentB ← Bj + AlignmentB
    j ← j - 1
  }
}
```

The psuedo-code has been taken from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman-Wunsch_algorithm) page on Wikipedia. For more information on the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm, please have a look at [this](http://www.slideshare.net/avrilcoghlan/the-needleman-wunsch-algorithm) presentation.